# Write separate messages with unix domain sockets

Tags: c, sockets, unix, unix-socket

I am currently learning to program with unix domain sockets and I have a question about it.
What is the standard way to separate message?
E.g. A server writes two messages and the client needs can do two reads to get the message.
I guess I could "define" my own protocol by always appending a certain char sequence at the end of each message, but this does not seem right.
The null char seems to get thrown away when writing to a socket.
I would be really grateful for some clarification, especially if it comes within the next 2 hours :D.

Comment: If you are writing both the server and the client programs you know what to expect. You therefore can perform one write()/read() transaction per message.

Comment: The situation is that I have a server and 2 clients which play tic tac toe. They either get a "your turn" message a "end of game" message or the move from the opponent. I know there are several workarounds(work with expected values, acking every transaction tcp style etc.) two send two messages in a row from the server but I feel like they are workarounds and I just simply would like to know if there is a standard way to separate messages.

Comment: @asblarf You are talking about datagram sockets. Just to make it clear for the OP, that has no chance of ever working with stream sockets.

Comment: @NicholasWilson A ping-pong mode for a TCP perf test like netperf actually acts like what I'm describing. One send() followed by one recv() from the client and vice verse on the server side. You could do the same with datagrams using UDP (netpef actually allows UDP tests). This logic has nothing to do with whether you're having a connection-oriented approach or not. But maybe I didn't get what you meant.

Comment: @Asblarf There seem to be a lot of newbies on SO who think two write()s in a row will come out as two read()s! That's what the question is about: writing two messages at once, so if he's using stream sockets, he has to manually delimit the messages. Just wanted to be clear for him...

Comment: @NicholasWilson Oh, alright. Got it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up "unix sockets" usually refers to "unix domain socket", a special form of IPC.

> The null char seems to get thrown away when writing to a socket

That's unlikely. You're probably no writing right.

> but this does not seem right

A simpler way would be to precede each "message" with a header containing the length. For example

```
         +---+---------+---+-------+
         | 3 |         | 5 | ...   |
         +---+---------+---+-------+
```

---

An even simpler approach would be to use a protocol that has notions of messages, i.e. something like UDP or SCTP where a `send` equates to at most one `recv`.

Answer (score 3):

With [`SOCK_DGRAM`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/unix.7.html) socket you'll get one-to-one correspondence between writes from the source and reads on the destination.

With `SOCK_STREAM` you do need your *application-level protocol* on top of the stream the socket provides. The usual choices are:

- **fixed-length messages**, just read until you get enough bytes,
- small **fixed-length header** for each message that tells length and maybe type of what follows,
- **delimited messages** (drawback here is that the delimiter cannot appear in the messages themselves),
- **self-describing** formats (xml, asn.1, etc.)